# Thinkpad T450 Wifi AC 7265 is not working in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I had purchased new laptop Lenovo T450 few days ago. I chose it because I want everything works out of the box, but unfortunately it didn't

The wireless wasn't show up. I have dual boot with Windows 10 and the wireless working very well in windows.

```
OS: Ubuntu 15.05 Vivid

Kernel: 3.19.0-15-generic

Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095b] (rev 59)
```

Wireless Info

```
########## wireless info START ##########


Report from: 21 Sep 2015 10:41 WIB +0700


Booted last: 22 Sep 2015 00:25 WIB +0700


Script from: 14 Jul 2015 17:04 UTC +0000


##### release ###########################


Distributor ID:    Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 15.04

Release:    15.04

Codename:    vivid


##### kernel ############################


Linux 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


##### lspci #############################


00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM [8086:15a2] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:2226]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e


03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095b] (rev 59)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5212]




##### PCMCIA card info ##################

[empty]

##### rfkill ############################

[empty]

##### lsmod #############################


cfg80211              540672  0

wmi                    20480  0



##### iwconfig ##########################


eth0      no wireless extensions.


lo        no wireless extensions.


##### iw reg get ########################


Region: Asia/Jakarta (based on set time zone)


country 00: DFS-UNSET
(2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A)
(2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
(2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
(5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
(5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-IR


[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]

remove iwlwifi \

(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \

&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

I had tried:

1. Live cd 15.04: not working
2. Upgrade kernel 4.2: not working
3. Live cd 15.10beta: not working
4. sudo apt-get install linux-firmware: not working
5. copy iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.17.12.0.tgz contents to /lib/firmware/ : not working

Additional info:

```
root@padnix:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | tail 
[    4.018204] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    4.018206] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.018208] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[    6.618120] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[    6.813747] input: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/input/input6
[    6.902236] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[    6.902242] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[  466.773269] thinkpad_acpi: EC reports that Thermal Table has changed
[ 2213.442121] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[ 2213.442124] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
```

Shows nothing on dmesg | grep iwl:

```
jim@padnix:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
jim@padnix:~$
```

Doing grep iwlwifi:

```
jim@padnix:~$ grep "iwlwifi" /etc/modprobe.d/*
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:remove iwlwifi \
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
```

Any help would be great.

Thank you so much

Comment: What does `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | tail` output?

Comment: @Pilot6 I added additional info about modprobe

Comment: So the driver is loaded now. You probably blacklisted it somewhere.

Comment: Add output of `grep "iwlwifi" /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: I'd also like to see: `dmesg | grep iwl`.

Comment: @Pilot6 Updated the question after doing: `grep "iwlwifi" /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: @chili555 Show nothing when doing: `dmesg | grep iwl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095b] (rev 59) Subsystem: Intel
>   Corporation Device [8086:5212]

I think the problem is that the subsystem ID 8086:5212 is not yet covered in iwlwifi. Please open the backports package you compiled. Drill down to drivers > net > wireless > iwlwifi > pcie. Open the file drv.c with any text editor, like gedit. Scroll down to line 406.

Here, I've used some guesswork. I assume this is a 2ac_cfg device. We will simply change an unneeded line to needed. Change:

```
{IWL_PCI_DEVICE(0x095B, 0x9200, iwl7265_2ac_cfg)},
```

To read:

```
{IWL_PCI_DEVICE(0x095B, 0x5212, iwl7265_2ac_cfg)},
```

Spacing, punctuation, brackets, etc. are crucial and must be perfect. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Now:

```
cd backports-20150731
make clean
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot. Any improvement?

Comment: omg man, you're really a god. **It works!** Connect flawlessly now. Last question: Do I need recompile like this everytime I upgrade kernel or dist?

Comment: Yes, as above described.